# Insert multiple dates from Monthcalendar into Access-mdb

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm currently trying to insert multiple Dates into an Access-Database. 
The Code i use to do this Looks like this:

```
string start = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
string end = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End.ToShortDateString();
DateTime startDay = Convert.ToDateTime(start);
DateTime endDay = Convert.ToDateTime(end);
_startDate = startDay;
_endDate = endDay;
do
{
    var VacationDate = _startDate.ToShortDateString();
    var VacationStart = DateTime.MinValue.ToShortTimeString();
    var VacationEnd = DateTime.MinValue.ToShortTimeString();
    var VacationPause = DateTime.MinValue.ToShortTimeString();
    var Worktime = "08:00";
    var Comments = "on Vacation";       
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", VacationDate);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start", VacationStart);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("End", VacationEnd);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pause", VacationPause);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Worktime", Worktime);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comments", Comments);      
    command.CommandText = "insert into " + user + " (Date, Start, End, Pause, Worktime, Comments) values (@Date, @Start, @End, @Pause, @Worktime, @Comments)";
    command.Connection = con;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();      
    string query = "select * from " + user;
    command.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataAdapter Daten = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable Datenquelle = new DataTable();
    Daten.Fill(Datenquelle);        
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Datenquelle;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = true;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    int totalRowHeight = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        totalRowHeight += row.Height;
    dataGridView1.Height = totalRowHeight;
    this.Height = dataGridView1.Height + 100;       
    _startDate = _startDate.AddDays(1);
}
while (_startDate <= _endDate);
{
    Debug.WriteLine(startDay);
    startDay = startDay.AddDays(1);
}
```

So far my Code seems to work so that i can add say three Dates if you select three Dates in the Monthcalendar. 
But i don't get the actual Dates. All i get is, for example, 3 following entries in my database with the same date. (Which is the startdate)

Maybe i just am to codeblind now to see my error....if someone could enlighten me why it only inserts my initial startDate and not the following selected days i'd be really grateful. :)

Thanks in advance to everyone answering.

Comment: *"3 following entries"* ... they seem to have gotten lost. -- Why do you have the SELECT query inside the loop where you INSERT records? Shouldn't it come afterwards?

Comment: @Andre451 thanks for your comment. 
It is just a part of my actual Code. I have the select query already way above to start my datagrid. But i wanted to refresh the datagrid with the new entries so i made a SELECT after the INSERT to get the new data properly displayed. 

(Maybe there are better ways to do this? I'm still pretty new to coding and especially working with databases) :D

Comment: You define Vacationday but insert VacationDate

Comment: @Johanness woops. Thanks for the comment and sorry for that. I translated the Code so everyone could follow what it does because i wrote it in my language - seems like i missed that somehow but in the actual Code Definition and inserted day are the same. :)

Comment: I am not familiar enough with c# but think the problem could be that multiple definition of the same variable? Try putting the var outside the loop (and if that doesnt help, it would be good to remove as much code as possible to only have the lines that cause the problem.

Comment: @Johanness i'm not sure what you meant....i'm only declaring each variable once? 
I already removed some Code that wasn't needed...this is the bare Minimum so i can still get it working. :( 
(I also tried your Suggestion moving the variables outside the Loop but that didn't do it unfortunately....but thanks for your comment)

Comment: What I mean is: if you have the var statement inside the do-loop the compiler will have to deal with it several times. And I just wasn't sure if that was what created your problem. By removing everything unnecessary I meant: reduce the code to just one variable (the one that interests you (the other ones are the minimum anyways)) and remove formatting code that is not really necessary to understand the problem. Then step through your code and check all the values. Where are they not what they should be? That would make the life of anyone who wants to help much easier

Answer (score 1):

So for everyone who might encounter the same problem as i did:

I apparently forgot to clear my Parameters after declaring them. So a simple

```
command.Parameters.Clear();
```

did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above: Does this work?

```
string start = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
string end = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End.ToShortDateString();
DateTime startDay = Convert.ToDateTime(start);
DateTime endDay = Convert.ToDateTime(end);
_startDate = startDay;
_endDate = endDay;
var VacationDate = _startDate.ToShortDateString();
do
{
    VacationDate = _startDate.ToShortDateString();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("vDate", VacationDate);
    command.CommandText = "insert into " + user + " (Date) values (@vDate)";
    command.Connection = con;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();      
    string query = "select * from " + user;
    command.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataAdapter Daten = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable Datenquelle = new DataTable();
    Daten.Fill(Datenquelle);        
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Datenquelle;
    _startDate = _startDate.AddDays(1);
}
while (_startDate <= _endDate);
{
    Debug.WriteLine(startDay);
    startDay = startDay.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: aaaah ok now i see what you meant. Thanks for explaining. Unfortunately that doesn't work either...

Comment: ... doesn't work is not enough. If you want help you have to do something yourself. I explicitly explained how you could get more information that would help anyone willing to help to find out where the problem lies. I have one more guess - In the code snipet you didn't create the OleDb command: `OleDbCommand command = new 
            OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);`

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. Sorry if i'm a bit slow at understanding. As i said i'm really new at this.....
I'm unsure how to get more Information because i don't get any Errors or Debug Report. 
The Connection is declared outside of the Code so i can use it multiple times in other parts of the Code. 
It really seems to be "only" an issue with how to get the startDay.AddDays(1); into vDate...but i can't really figure out why since it should (?) take the new startDay when it runs the Code a second time....at least that's what i thought. Thanks again for your help.